# Secure Forms Timeout - ExpressionEngine - FreeForm

Tags: expressionengine, freeform

Using freeform with ExpressionEngine 2.7.0 returns the following error on submit:

`You are not authorized to perform this action - Reason: Secure Forms Timeout`

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**:

In ExpressionEngine 2.7.0 there is a feature called "Process form data in Secure Mode" which prevents freeform submitting the data.

**Solution**:

in the EE control panel, goto
`Admin -> Security And Privacy -> Security And Sessions`
Change the `Process form data in Secure Mode?` setting to `No`

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  What version of Freeform are you using?   Are you really seeing this error after a timeout or does it happen on immediate submission?  You shouldn't have to turn off secure form processing to get FreeForm to work.